# MYSQL AND OR On Many To Many Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Kind of a convoluted question but, basically I have a many to many table `word_relationships`:

```
+-----+--------+--------+
|  ID | WORD_A | WORD_B |
+-----+--------+--------+
|  1  |  784   |  893   |
+-----+--------+--------+
|  2  |  930   |  839   |
+-----+--------+--------+
|  3  |  093   |  647   |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

it is a list of `word a` and `word b` relationships.  I need to query to find if the relationship between word_a and word_b exists.  What would be the proper syntax for this if the words can be either word A OR word b?

In my head it's

```
w1 = 784
w2 = 893
"SELECT ID FROM word_relationships WHERE WORD_A = w1 OR WORD_B = w1 AND WORD_A = w2 OR WORD_B = w2";
```

This doesn't seem to work because I get back a result for any match.  Anyone familiar with this situation and know the proper syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
  id 
FROM 
  word_relationships
WHERE 
 (Word_A = w1 AND Word_B = w2)
OR 
 (Word_A = w2 AND Word_B = w1)
```

Comment: REally? I was just missing some parenthesis??

Comment: And a few changes in the order of your comparisons. :) +1 to your question, BTW - nice job of including all the information we needed to provide an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can just put parenthesis in your where clauses to combine the ORs properly.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM word_relationships 
WHERE (WORD_A = w1 OR WORD_B = w1) 
AND (WORD_A = w2 OR WORD_B = w2)
```

I'm not totally sure I'm understanding your intention for the query though.  Hope that helps.

BTW, the reason you were getting back all of the results is because of the [order of precedence for SQL operators.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Since AND is evaluated before OR, it meant that by default the clause was grouped as follows:

```
WHERE WORD_A = w1 
OR (WORD_B = w1 AND WORD_A = w2) 
OR WORD_B = w2
```

which would return many more than you were expecting.

Comment: I just need to see that the relationship exists between the two words.  The relationship will exist if they share a row in this table.  Trying out the sql now.

Comment: Seth, thanks so much for your response.  Ken got his in first, so I gave him the checkmark, but I gave you an upvote for your troubles.