# How to use one or more OR and AND in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MYSQL AND OR On Many To Many Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712358/mysql-and-or-on-many-to-many-table)

I want to do a mysql query where data is retrieved from a database with some regulation.

I want to check which entries are similar to var1 or var2 or var3 and etc. AND are smaller than a given ID.

Like

```
SELECT * 
FROM database 
WHERE name = var1 
    OR name = var2 
    OR name = var3 
    AND id < 200
```

But the above line don't really works. Also when there is no more entry (which id is smaller than 200) it shows me however some entries.

Do you know what I mean? The query should select data which contains one of my wanted names AND which are smaller than an ID...

I have there a logic thinking problem...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) with logical operators. When in doubt, use parenthesis.

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE (name = var1 OR name = var2 OR name = var3) AND id < 200
```

Your original query was interpreted as follows because the `AND` has higher precedence.

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE name = var1 OR name = var2 OR (name = var3 AND id < 200)
```

#### Update

As commented by **Rocket**, you could condense your `OR` statements to [`IN`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) since they operate on the same field. Doing so would remove the need for parentheses.

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE name IN (var1,var2,var3) AND id < 200
```

Nonetheless, understanding the difference between the two original queries is important as you inevitably will write queries with multiple conditions.

Comment: +1, parenthesis are your friends.

Comment: You can also do `WHERE name IN (var1,var2,var3) AND id < 200`

Comment: @Rocket, Agreed. I saw the same thing. But wanted to focus on the specific of the question :)

Comment: I figured I'd mention it, as it would work for this specific scenario.

Comment: thanks. seems that it works now. wow, just a bracket was missing... but thank you very much for the tip (also to @Rocket)!

Comment: @rocket and jason mccreary: last question. is not IN looking in the field where the string is contained? like when i'm looking for "john", and in var2 there is an entry with "johnn", it also presents me this entry? or does it look exactly for "john" (with one n)? and when it is so, which query would be faster (or more professional)?

Comment: @JohnBrunner: `name IN (var1, var2)` is jut shorthand for `name = var1 OR name = var2`.  It only finds exact matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses to set the priority of the logic expressions:

```
SELECT * FROM database_table WHERE (name = var1 OR name = var2 OR name = var3) AND id < 200
```

Comment: also to you thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please read below.

***[Is there a difference between these two queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815876/is-there-a-difference-between-these-two-queries/10815979#10815979)***

You will get idea what is ***importance*** of parenthesis in OR and AND.

Comment: and last but not least also thanks to you for the tip and link!